# Nvidia Graphics driver in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

My laptop has 1 GB Nvidia graphics card.

When i used windows i needed to install graphics card.

Now i am using ubuntu 14.04 with windows 8.1 as dual boot.

Do i need install a graphics driver for ubuntu? if yes how?

Comment: What type of graphics card ? Nvidia, AMD ?

Comment: its Nvidia graphics card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install the drivers for an Nvidia card, you have two choices

First the tested stable driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

Or the update version

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates
```

I recommend the updated version but it may have bugs, you can always just run the first command to change it if you have issues but I never have.

Comment: how to check if installed or not?

Comment: Just  run the command again and it will say the package is already installed or open the software and updates app and choose the additional drivers tab, is the one you downloaded selected ?