# Changing screen resolution of GRUB menu

Tags: grub2, 18.04, nvidia, display-resolution

When I switch on my computer, I get the GRUB menu in very low resolution (640 x 480).

**I would like to know how I can change the resolution of GRUB.**

To get information about my current resolution, I applied the following (instructions from [Marmayogi](https://askubuntu.com/users/617387/marmayogi) in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129516/black-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts)):

- Pressed "c" key to enter GRUB's command line `grub>` at start up.
- Executed the following GRUB commands: `grub> set pager=1` and `grub> videoinfo` to get the available screen resolutions and my resolution marked with a "*".

But I do not know how to actually change the resolution.

Things to take into account: I am using a Nvidia graphics card RTX 2070 and have installed Nvidia driver version 410, and I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to leave it set for 640x480. Setting it to any higher resolution just makes the GRUB menu tiny, and harder to view.

However, if you **must** change it...

`sudo pico /etc/default/grub`

Find:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

And change it to:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

changing the resolution as desired.

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: Wasn't there a similar question about three months ago we both answered on this?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Probably :-) It's all a blur.