# Can't install Nvidia Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GTX 1050 Mobile, AMD Ryzen 5 2500u)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xorg

I've tried for hours to install nvidia drivers for my laptop. The standard nvidia-390, the newer nvidia-418 through the repo, various other versions, the .run files from Nvidia's website, tried changing into lightdm, tried the various grub parameters like nomodeset etc. Last thing I tried was installing nvidia-384 because why the hell not at this point, which resulted in a login loop. Not the first time this is happening either, the standard nvidia-390 does the same and I have no idea why. Has someone managed to install nvidia drivers in a similar system that could help me? Thank you.
**Edit:** I've disabled secure boot, so unless my BIOS is lying to me, this shouldn't be an issue...

**EDIT 2:**
After installing nvidia-driver-418 I can boot the system, but the command nvidia-settings give me this output:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:2477): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:22:32.065: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 12:22:32.070: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 12:22:32.070: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

And the nvidia-settings window is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: I've disabled secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem while trying to install the Nvidia drivers for the RTX 2070.

May I suggest you look at how I solved the problem in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129516/black-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts), in case it helps.

The two important things to note are:

- You need to install a driver which is compatible with your graphics card. You can check compatible drivers on the [Nvidia website](https://www.geforce.com/drivers). From what I see there, the latest version 418 supports your graphics card (but please check yourself to make sure).
- Make sure you use the command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-418` when installing your driver (not `sudo apt-get install nvidia-418` which is obsolete).

Please let me know how if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does not work unfortunately, at least not the last 3 or so times I've tried it (I always purge nvidia packages beforehand, so it's not that). I'm now reinstalling Ubuntu but with the third-party software option checked, I think I read somewhere that this may help. If it doesn't change anything, I'll install 418 and get back to you.

Comment: Tried installing nvidia-driver-418, didn't work, please see edited post.

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but have you tried blacklisting nouveau? Check out Marmayogi's  answer on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129516/black-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts) for instructions.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to update kernel. See Frank's answer on the same post for instructions. I hope one of these options work...

Comment: Updating to newest kernel and blacklisting nouveau doesn't work. Currently stuck at black screen on boot...