# Unable to get nvidia running on ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I'm unable to get nvidia gpu running on my ubuntu 18.04.2 PC.
I tried to do installation using `apt-get install nvidia-driver-VERSION` command with `391`, `418` and `450` VERSION, but everytime without luck. I'm always getting black screen after logging in. I have the same with `.run` files from nvidia website.
I also tried to blacklist nouveau default driver using https://askubuntu.com/a/1129961. After blacklisting ubuntu had problems with determining my screen resolution, so I assume nouveau got disabled.

My GPU: Gigabyte GTX 980 Ti.

Comment: You did everything wrong. Remove all Nvidia packages that you installed and disable all Nvidia PPAs. You can see all the installed Nvidia packages in Synaptic ( `sudo apt install synaptic` ). Then run `sudo apt update`. Finally run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot`

Comment: and there is no 450 in the repos, the most curent afiak is 418.  you can get 430 with the grapic drivers ppa but evne 435 is still in testing, it's only available in 19.10 testing

Comment: @TrailRider Nvidia 430 driver is in the default 18.04 repositories. It's bad advice to use PPAs for everything.

Comment: The PPA is updated to 435.21; been running it for about a week.

Comment: I was not aware that 430 is in the repos, it was missing for 19.04

Comment: @ajgringo619 you must be using testing?  it doesn't show up for Disco(19.04) https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=disco  it does show up for 19.10(Eoan) https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=eoan

Comment: @karel so why was I not able to install 430 in 19.04 without adding the ppa? bug?

Comment: I have uninstalled `apt-get purge nvidia*`, disabled blacklisting of nouveau and everything started to run. I think I'm in good point to try again with something different, because I need official NVIDIA drivers to have CUDA running.

Comment: @TrailRider - I'm running Mint 19.2, added the repo like this: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. Is this different than what comes with 19.04?

Comment: @ajgringo619 ohhh that is bc Mint is based on 18.04 so you use that, for some reason it is not in 19.04's version of the ppa

Comment: @karel 430+ are not available in the offical 19.04 repos  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia I was not advising to use a ppa "for everything" but based on my use of 19.04 it was not available any other way, logically if it's not available in the newest Ubuntu it's not available in the older ones

Comment: Could you solve it? I’m in the same situation.