# POST and GRUB give blank/black screen but login screen appears eventually. Nvida K600

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I've changed the video card and now I'm missing the POST and GRUB output, nothing is displayed to begin with, I hear four individual beeps ~10s apart then see a flashing cursor before the screen goes black again (something I've done means I currently get blocky noise on the screen) and then displays the login GUI. It runs fine after that, but I need to get the initial low level boot output back for supportability.

I've installed the latest Nvida driver - 418 - which lists the Quadro K600 as supported. I've also tried the 390 driver suggested in the post below but it makes no difference.

Grub contains GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset...

I've followed this post [Black screen at boot after Nvidia driver installation on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129516/black-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts) but can't clear the issue.

20.04.2 dual boot, with a Nvidia Quadro K600 video card.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Was unable to access UEFI interface until the motherboard backup was cleared (battery removed whilst power off); GRUB is back now... the Nvida version makes no difference to this issue.