# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot in 5.8.0-63-generic

Tags: boot, 20.04

I don't know how it happened, but most likely after updating the packages, I can no longer run `5.8.0-63-generic`. After the loading animation, I just get a purple screen. I tried to press `Ctrl + Alt + F1` or `Ctrl + Alt + Delete` after that I see my account and login screen for a second, after that the screen freezes and I cannot see the keyboard input. At the same time the screen resolution is rather strange like 640x480.

I tried to use `Advanced options for Ubuntu` after BIOS logo. I have 4 options:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-63-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-63-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-59-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-59-generic (recovery mode)
```

First 2 options not working at all. In recovery mode I got this:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elB6T.jpg)

Then everything freezes and nothing happens.

In `5.8.0-59-generic` option everything works fine. I tried to determine what happened after update and checked update list of packages:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lxxv.png)

Can somebody give me any advice to boot into `5.8.0-63-generic` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booted into 5.8.0-59-generic and installed ssh:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ssh
sudo reboot
```

Booted into 5.8.0-63-generic and connected via ssh and then:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

After reboot everything started working again. I was guided by this post:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1129890/884692