# Wired and wireless network gone after purging nvidia drivers /problems with latest kernel version

Tags: drivers, nvidia, reboot

I was getting blank nvidia x server screen so I reinstalled my nvidia drivers. When I rebooted my laptop, it was giving a black screen. I followed these instructions below to boot ubuntu after setting nomodeset
[Black screen at boot after Nvidia driver installation on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129516/black-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts?newreg=a13b452927d04fc79851d6e14e6f3410)
I was successful in booting but I have lost both of my wired and wireless networks. Ethernet is not working and there is no way I can install any package. Please help! I do not want to reinstall ubuntu as I have already configured the systems with many softwares

P.S: I am using ubuntu 20.04 and nvidia driver was 470 which was working fine before

Thanks

Comment: Understand that nomodeset is supposed to be a temporary troubleshooting step. If you can boot when using it, your Nvidia driver didn't get installed correctly. Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS? The Nvidia problem has nothing to do with your networks not working. I'd troubleshoot that first.

Comment: So there has been some progress since then: I went into advanced ubuntu settings and chose an older version of kernel. Now my wifi and ethernet both are working plus I installed nvidia driver. But the latest kernal version that I was using previously still does not have any network. And yes secure booth is disabled

Comment: There may be a problem with the latest kernel. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot` and `uname -r` and `dkms status`. Are you up to date with `Software Updater`?

Comment: Latest kernel was running fine but I guess I did not purge/auto remove nvidia drivers before reinstalling them..can this cause the issue?
I booted into latest kernel version and the output for commands are as follows: 5.11.0-43-generic
nvidia, 470.86, 5.11.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.11.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.11.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Sorry I am new to this and don't know how to add the output for ls -al /boot in comments as it's too long :/

Comment: We were all newbies once :-) With the commands, you do those in terminal, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, paste the clipboard at the end of your question, select the pasted text, click the {} icon to properly format it to human-readable, then save. As you've seen, the comments aren't the place for much output. Please do the commands again.

Comment: From what little I could see, I'd say that Nvidia didn't get installed on the -43 kernel, and your wireless card driver didn't either. I'll wait to see the new output before I can give more details.

Comment: Status please...